# R: read.arff error

Tags: java, r, weka

I am starting to work with Weka in R and I got stuck at the first step. I converted my `csv` file into `arff` file and I did this using an online converter, but when i tried to read it into R I got the following error message.

```
  require(RWeka)
  A <- read.arff("Environmental variables all overviewxlsx.arff")
Error in .jnew("weka/core/Instances", .jcast(reader, "java/io/Reader")) : 
 java.io.IOException: no valid attribute type or invalid enumeration, read Token[[°C]],    line 6
```

Does anyone have an idea that could help me?

Thanks!

p.s. the proper package (RWeka) is already installed.

Comment: i think its "degree" before the Celsius.

Comment: Could you please post the `.arff` file?  It could be that the issue is simply, as Bhanu points out, the degree symbol in `°C`

Comment: In R you can read in your data from .csv format and still use Weka functions, should you want to skip the conversion process.  (A <- read.csv("Environmental variables all overviewxlsx.csv")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because read.arff() returns a dataframe you could skip the conversion process and use read.csv().

```
    train_arff<-read.arff(file.choose())
    str(train_arff)

    'data.frame':   14 obs. of  5 variables:
    $ outlook    : Factor w/ 3 levels "sunny","overcast",..: 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 1 1 3 ...
    $ temperature: Factor w/ 3 levels "hot","mild","cool": 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 ...
    $ humidity   : Factor w/ 2 levels "high","normal": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
    $ windy      : logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
    $ play       : Factor w/ 2 levels "yes","no": 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...

    train_csv<-read.csv(file.choose())
    str(train_csv)

    'data.frame':   14 obs. of  5 variables:
    $ outlook    : Factor w/ 3 levels "overcast","rainy",..: 3 3 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 2 ...
    $ temperature: Factor w/ 3 levels "cool","hot","mild": 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 3 ...
    $ humidity   : Factor w/ 2 levels "high","normal": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
    $ windy      : logi  FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
    $ play       : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
```

Otherwise your .arff file should have this [format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html)

Comment: Thought I would turn my comment into an answer.